# Implementing a C++ hashtable class using template

Tags: c++, templates, hash, runtime, hashtable

I am trying to implement a hashtable in C++ that sort of like the Java version

I would like it has the form of

```
template <class Key, class Value> 
class hashtable {
...
}
```

Soon enough I notice that I need to somehow convert Key into a number, so that I can use the simple hash function

```
int h(int hashkey) { 
    return hashkey%some_prime;
}
```

But the headache is, Key type is only known at run time. Is it possible to check what type Key is on run time in C++. Or I have to create this hashtable class with different type manually? That is easier to do but ugly. Anyone know an elegant solution?

Comment: Have you considered `std::unordered_map` instead?

Comment: Implementing a hashtable is a good learning exercise, but you will want to look at the documentation (and possibly the code) for Billy's suggestion on `std::unordered_map`, to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am actually doing a learning exercise, and I may need to add some in house feature to this implementation later. A stupid question, where can I look at the implementation of std:unordered_map?

Comment: If you are interested in looking at the implementation of std::unordered_map, on a linux machine, it usually starts in the /usr/include/c++/<your_version>/unordered_map, and looking for other header files included, such as tr1_impl/hashtable.

However, it is far from trivial to understand the implementation.

Comment: make your hash function the third parameter of your template,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like try to implement a "generic" one, perhaps you can start with a skeleton much like this:

```
template <class T, class K>
struct HashEntry {  // you would need this to deal with collision
    T curr;
    K next;
}

template <class V, size_t n>
class HashTable {
    void insert(V v)
    {
        ...
        size_t idx = v->getHashCode(n);
        ...
    }
private:
    HashEntry <V> table_[n];

}
```

It is usually instantiated with some pointer type, to figure out where a pointer should go, it requires the type implement member function "getHashCode" ...

Answer (score 3):

C++ templates are usually duck typed, meaning that you can explicitly cast to an integeral type in the template, and all types that implement the appropriate conversion can be used as a key. That has the disadvantage of requiring that the classes implement the conversion operator in such a fashion that the hash function will be decent, which is asking for a lot.

You could instead provide a function template

```
template<typename T> int hash (T t);
```

Along with specializations for the built in types, and any user that wants to use a custom class as key will just have to provide his own specialzation. I think this is a decent approach.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a few misunderstandings.  Key type is known at compile time - that's the whole point of using templates.  Secondly, there is really no such thing as a completely generic hash function that will work on any type.  You need to implement different hash functions for different types, using function overloading or template specialization.  There are many common hash functions used for strings, for example.

Finally, C++11 includes a standard hash table ([std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) which you can use instead of implementing your own.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I was clear about the run time thing at the beginning but got confused after searching on the web for a while. unordered_map is very similar to what I want. Where can I look at the implementation of it?

Comment: pretty much any compiler supporting C++11 should ship with an implementation. I suggest having a look at the latest release of GCC.

Comment: [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) the status page for the library implementation bundled with GCC, see entry 23.5.4.